# Dia: straight line for association in class diagram

Tags: associations, class-diagram, dia

In Dia, by default (at least on Debian Wheezy out of the box) the lines representing the associations between two classes are not straight but follow the grid.
Is there a way to make the association lines between classes in dia straight?

Answer (score 1):

In the UML symbol sheet, the Association symbol is a zig-zag, meaning it will only ever move orthogonally to the sheet. Depending on whether you're using all of the features of the Association symbol (multiplicity, label, etc), you could use the standard Line symbol in its place. The Line symbol (L) can be given the necessary beginning and end diamonds or arrows and you can attach a Text element to the line. What you mostly miss out on is the multiplicity labels on either end of the line (though it would seem those would be less valuable if your line was diagonal).

I hope this helps and is acceptable.

Comment: How do you attach a text to a standard line (L)? I see no option for that.